# Spyder will not launch from Anaconda 2019.10 Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

After a fresh installation of `Anaconda 2019.10`, I'm unable to launch Spyder straight out of the box. I'm surprised to see this error upon launching Spyder from the Anaconda toolbar:

```
File "C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 24, in show_warning raise RuntimeError(message) RuntimeError: Please check Spyder installation requirements: spyder-kernels >= 1.0 is required (found 0.5.2).
```

I thought this would do the trick:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-kernels
```

But the same error is still being raised

Comment: Have you tried launching spyder through the anaconda-Navigator?

Comment: @spherical Yes, I have.

Comment: _spyder-kernels >= 1.0 is required (found 0.5.2)._ Can you check the version of `spyder-kernels` manually?

Answer (score 1):

In Anaconda click on environments.  Select the environment you want to use. When that environment loads. Then go to Home. When home loads go to Spyder icon. If it says install within the icon then click on install. Spyder is not automatically installed for all environments. You have to install it for each environment in Anaconda. I am surprised an update would cause a problem but perhaps the above procedure might correct the problem.